# Large UINavigationBar in transparent state can't return to default state

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm struggling with this issue for a couple of days now.

I have a view controller which should set the current navigation bar transparent. Just like the Apple Music app on the Artist page. I've kinda got it to work with something that really feels hacky.

### first version

On viewWillAppear:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated);
```

On viewDidAppear, I simply animate the navigation bar in again

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true);
```

Then when we are leaving, on viewWillDisappear:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

    // force a redraw of the navigation bar
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true;
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false;

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true);
})
```

This worked quite well until I've turned on large titles.

Then I tried to utilize the `transitionCoordinator`.

### second version

On viewWillAppear:

```
self.transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0
}, completion: nil)

self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated);
```

And basically the same thing on `viewWillDisappear` by turning the alpha back to 1.

But the problem remains, the large navigation bar stays transparent the small one seems to work.

Here a little GIF of the situation:

[image: Gif transparent navigation bar issue]

### The question

How do I solve this issue? Has anybody else encountered something similar, and how did you get around the problem if you haven't been able to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Eduard Unfortunately no, we had to work around the issue by disabling large titles.

Comment: :( that's something I wouldn't do. I found out that in order to workaround this you would have to play with barTintColor instead of background image. But by doing this you can't have a transparent navigation bar anymore ...